# How to test if a Python object is a module?

Tags: python

Python modules are objects too. So I would imagine it could be possible to test if a given object is a module(/package) this way:

```
>>> import sys, os, my_module
>>> isinstance(sys, ModuleClass)
True
>>> isinstance(os, ModuleClass)
True
>>> isinstance(my_module, ModuleClass)
True
>>> isinstance(5, ModuleClass)
False
```

Except "ModuleClass" is just a name I invented and I can't find in the docs if anything like it actually exists and what it's called.

Is there such a class at all? Is it somewhere in the docs that I've missed?

If not, is there another way to see if an object is a module? Even better if it's  implementation-agnostic.

(I'm using Python 2.7, but I guess it would also be interesting to know if 3.x has some new solution.)

It sounds like `hasattr(obj, '__package__')` ([PEP 366](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/)) is a possible stopgap, but AFAICT there's no special reason to feel sure that some future update won't put `__package__` into some other, totally unrelated objects. I'd prefer a solution that feels a bit more robust.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`inspect.ismodule`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.ismodule):

```
>>> import inspect
>>> import os
>>> os2 = object()
>>> inspect.ismodule(os)
True
>>> inspect.ismodule(os2)
False
```

Answer (score 13):

You can do:

```
from types import ModuleType
print isinstance(obj, ModuleType)
```

Comment: This is exactly how `inspect.ismodule` is defined.

Comment: Thanks guys! Both solutions are awesome!